# Fixing device coordinate system regardless of device orientation?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, coordinate-systems, sceneform

I am successfully converting (latitude, longitude) coordinates to (East, North) coordinates and am trying to figure out a way to accurately place the (East, North) coordinates in the AR world.

**Example of my current issue:**

Device coordinate system:

[image: Device coordinate system with positive and negative x, y and z axes, with origin facing camera located on the positive side of the z axis.]

A conversion from a (latitude, longitude) coordinate gives me an (East, North) coordinate of,

```
(+x, 0, +z) where x=East, z=North
```

Now, if I am facing Northwards the EN coordinate will be placed behind me, as the forward facing axis is `-z` . If I am facing Southwards, the EN coordinate will be placed behind me once again because it is dependent on my device's orientation.

**My question:**

In ARCore is it possible to fix a device's coordinate system no matter what orientation the device is in? Or is there an algorithm that takes into account device orientation and allows static placement of Anchors?

**EDIT:**

I posted this same question on the ARCore-Sceneform GitHub and these are the answers I received:

[image: GitHub Question Thread]

Answer (score 0):

At first, let's see what [Google ARCore engineers say about World coordinates](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/c/group/concepts):

> **World Coordinate Space**
>
> As ARCore's understanding of the environment changes, it adjusts its model of the world to keep things consistent. When this happens, ***the numerical location (coordinates) of the camera and anchors can change significantly to maintain appropriate relative positions of the physical locations they represent***.
>
> These changes mean that every frame should be considered to be in a completely unique world coordinate space. The numerical coordinates of anchors and the camera should never be used outside the rendering frame during which they were retrieved. If a position needs to be considered beyond the scope of a single rendering frame, either an anchor should be created or a position relative to a nearby existing anchor should be used.

[image]

But!

I firmly believe that a smartphone with its camera and sensors begin their way (in the ArSession) from relative center of coordinate space (it's relative for us, for ARCore it's absolute, of course):

```
// X, Y, Z coordinates must be counted from zero, mustn't they?

(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
```

Then, under certain circumstances, the world coordinate space might be changed.